# Powershell: Does ADDSForest promote a new domain controller, and if so, does that mean that ADDSDomainController does not need to be used?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, automation

I have noticed that installing ADDSForest in powershell will prompt for the domain name and a password, and promotes the domain controller, creating a forest and a domain controller in AD.
Can I use this command without installing ADDSDomainContoller? It seems to me like ADDSForest does the same thing as ADDSDomainController in regards to creating and promoting a domain controller, but also creates a forest in AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install-addsforest is used to create an Active Directory Forest Root Domain, i.e., a new forest, new domain, first DC, etc. Install-addsdomaincontroller does not create a forest root domain, instead it is typically reserved for installing an additional DC in an existing forest and domain.

EDIT
Install-adddsdomaincontroller does not need to be used if you're creating a root forest domain because install-addsforest will create\promote a Domain Controller during the root forest creation.  After your root forest domain is created, you'll most likely create an additional DC per Microsoft best practices and you will use install-addsdomaincontroller to promote a member server to a domain controller in the existing domain.